# SQL Server connection handling, connection pooling, lifetime and leaked connections

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, database-connection, connection-pooling, connection-leaks

I am trying to identify SQL connection leaks in my application. After some operations, when my application is idle (user not doing any activity), I see 7 connections with my database in the result set returned by `sp_who2`. The status for all connections is `Sleeping` and `Command` value for all of them is `AWAITING COMMAND`.

I am using connection pooling but `Connection Lifetime` is not specified in the connection string. This means that it's default value 0 will be used if I am right. Connection Lifetime having value zero means SQL server should not close connection ever, right?

I keep my application idle for some time (15-20 minutes) and then I see  that `sp_who2` does NOT show any connection with my database. I am wondering why I get this result when Connection Lifetime is zero. **Does SQL Server terminates unused connection after some time regardless of the Connection Lifetime value?**

**How can I identify which connection is open due to leakage and which is hanging around there due to connection pooling?**

My application supports SQL Server 2008, 2014 and 2016. It's ASP.NEt application.

Answer (score 0):

*Connection Lifetime having value zero means SQL server should not close connection ever, right?*

No. The rules used to purge the pool are not well documented AFAIK, but they can be closed by the pooler. Refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.

I don't think there is a reliable/documented method to identify pooled connections from within the database engine.